# TimePicker component was moved from `@mui/lab` to `@mui/x-date-pickers`

Tags: formik-material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I use formik-mui-lab to make  DatePicker but this warning appears
MUI: The TimePicker component was moved from `@mui/lab` to `@mui/x-date-pickers`.

You should use `import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'`
or `import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker'`

nots i want to use formik-mui-lab note @mui/lab
https://stackworx.github.io/formik-mui/docs/api/mui-lab // link site

You should use `import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'`
or `import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use formik-mui-lab and need to use the `TimePicker` component, you should import it from @mui/lab instead of @mui/x-date-pickers. Your import statement should look like this:

```
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/lab'
```

This will prevent the warning from appearing and ensure that you are using the correct version of the component for your needs.